uploading a multiple images o firebase and show them on screen
firstly : when i try to choose image from files and upload it, the page is refreshed.
secondly : when i upload the image, it appears twice on the screen.
thirdly : i want to upload just 4 images without repetition of the image.
PLEASE HELP AND THANK YOU.
  const [img, setImg] = useState(null);
  const [imgUrl, setImgUrl] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = async () => {
    if (img !== null) {
      const imgRef = ref(imageDb, `files/${v4()}`);
      try {
        const uploadTaskSnapshot = await uploadBytes(imgRef, img);
        const url = await getDownloadURL(uploadTaskSnapshot.ref);
        setImgUrl((prevUrls) => [...prevUrls, url]);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error uploading image:", error);
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchImages = async () => {
      try {
        const imgs = await listAll(ref(imageDb, "files"));
        const urls = await Promise.all(
          imgs.items.map(async (item) => {
            return await getDownloadURL(item);
          })
        );
        setImgUrl((prevUrls) => [...prevUrls, ...urls]);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching images:", error);
      }
    };

    fetchImages();
  }, []);

  return(
    <div>
      <input
        type="file"
        onChange={(e) => setImg(e.target.files[0])}
      />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Upload</button>
      <br />
      {imgUrl.map((url, index) => (
        <div>
          <img key={index} src={url} alt={`Image ${index}`} />
          <br />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )


are there any parameters passed to this component?

no just this parameters
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { imageDb } from "../firebase";
import { getDownloadURL, listAll, ref, uploadBytes } from "firebase/storage";
import { v4 } from "uuid";
